# Using "type" for a type synonym causes memory leak?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, type-systems

I have the following code as my hot loop.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Simulation.Simulator where

import Simulation.Common ()
import System.Random (RandomGen)
import Control.Monad.Random (Rand)

simulateUntil :: 
        (RandomGen g) =>
        Int                             ->      --Number of simulation steps
        a                               ->      --Initial model
        (a -> Rand g Bool)              ->      --Function to check if simulation should end
        (Float -> a -> Rand g a)        ->      --Update model one step
        Rand g a 
simulateUntil !num !model !done !update = do
        !stop <- done model
        if stop then return model 
        else do updateM <- update (1 / fromIntegral num) model
                simulateUntil num updateM done update
```

To try and make this loop more readable and more inline with the rest of my code I have added a type synonym in my Simulation.Common code:

```
type SearchEnv a = (RandomGen g) => Rand g a
```

I then changed the loop above to use this new type synonym which is used in all of my other code, the new loop is almost identical:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Simulation.Simulator where

import Simulation.Common

simulateUntil ::
        Int                             ->      --Number of simulation steps
        a                               ->      --Initial model
        (a -> SeachEnv Bool)              ->      --Function to check if simulation should end
        (Float -> a -> SearchEnv a)        ->      --Update model one step
        SearchEnv a 
simulateUntil !num !model !done !update = do
        !stop <- done model
        if stop then return model 
        else do updateM <- update (1 / fromIntegral num) model
                simulateUntil num updateM done update
```

Yet for some reason this last edition leaks memory, which show up as

```
FUN_1_0
```

when running with the "-h" option in GHC.

Is this expected behavior with "type" or is there something else happening?

Edit:
Here is the difference in memory usage as reported by GHC "-h" option:
With type synonym: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0kpC.png
After removing type synonym(reverting to the old code show at the top): https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4oZC.png

Comment: You can't have a type alias like `(RandomGen g) => Rand g a` without a compiler extension.  In these cases, an alias isn't a directly alias, so that's where your memory leak is probably coming from.  It's not recommended to make type aliases like that unless you have a very specific need to do so other than aesthetics.

Comment: The type alias indeed requires an extension.  However types like `foo :: Int -> Monad m => m Bool` do seem to be permitted without extensions, much to my surprise.

Comment: @TomEllis I would ask you to recheck that, GHCi 7.6.3 told me I needed `RankNTypes` for `foo :: Int -> Monad m => m Bool`; `foo n = return True`.

Comment: I did indeed need `RankNTypes` to compile the code. So if that is the reason, I think I understand.

Comment: @bheklilr: It works in 7.4.1, but perhaps it's a bug that was later fixed.

Comment: Well, `foo :: Int -> Monad m => m Bool` isn't actually a rank-2 type. It's just a non-standard way to write a rank-1 type. So it's actually somewhat strange that it required `RankNTypes` now (but admittedly, it isn't Standard Haskell either).

Comment: Small stylistic point: if you make your argument comments use syntax like "-- ^ Initial model" then Haddock can pick them up and put them in your docs. This is best practice.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I really should. I have not put any effort into my comments and this is really the extent of it. The intention is to never let anyone competent in Haskell to ever see the mess of a codebase so I probably won't bother with Haddock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, GHC represents type class constraints as function arguments in the form of a type class dictionary. So if you have a type `RandomGen g => Rand g a`, it effectively gets turned into `RandomGen -> Rand a`. What this means is that whenever the result of a call to `done` or `update` is used, the internal type class function must be recomputed. Incidentally, this also means that the result can't be shared since GHC doesn't automatically memoize functions. Internally, the types of `done` and `update` are sort of like this:

```
done   :: a          -> (RandomGen -> Rand Bool)
update :: Float -> a -> (RandomGen -> Rand a)
```

I think the specific problem is that you're passing the result of `update` back in to the recursive call and each time that value is needed, the internal function with the type class dictionary must be called.

In your first version, the `RandomGen` type dictionary is getting passed to the top-level function, so no extra "hidden" functions that need to get called other than that.

GHC is usually pretty good at optimizing this kind of thing away, but I suspect that this is the culprit.

Here's a simpler example of this in action. We can observe the time and memory it takes to compute an expression in GHCI with the `:set +s` command:

```
λ> let fib n = if n <= 1 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
λ> let { n :: Num a => a; n = fib 30 }
λ> let { m :: Int; m = fib 30 }
λ> :set +s
λ> m
1346269
(2.04 secs, 695163424 bytes)
λ> m
1346269
(0.00 secs, 1073792 bytes)
λ> 
λ> n
1346269
(2.01 secs, 669035464 bytes)
λ> n
1346269
(2.02 secs, 669032064 bytes)
```

Here is another example. This is sort of like the `fib` function except it adds some constant in each recursive call.

```
λ> let { fib1 :: (Num a, Ord a, Num b) => Int -> a -> b;                fib1 m n = if n <= 1 then 1 else fromIntegral m + fib1 m (n-1) + fib1 m (n-2) }
λ> let { fib2 :: Int -> ((Num a, Ord a) => a) -> ((Num a, Ord a) => a); fib2 m n = if n <= 1 then 1 else fromIntegral m + fib2 m (n-1) + fib2 m (n-2) }
λ> :set +s
λ> fib1 1 30
2692537
(2.59 secs, 993139888 bytes)
λ> fib2 1 30
2692537
(17.98 secs, 7884453496 bytes)
```

Since `m` gets turned into a function in the second `fib` definition, it has to get called every time it is needed so no sharing can occur and this results in time and space leaks.

Comment: This does make sense and would explain the reason for the slow down. I would really like someone else to chime in and confirm, or more up votes on this answer before I accept either this or the above answer.

Comment: This is a more complete answer than mine though I still don't think it gets to the heart of the matter because the `fib` example seems quite different to `simulateUntil`.  I wonder if it's just because GHC does not optimize well the polymorphic recursion in the latter case.

Comment: I added an example which has an argument with a rank-2 constraint so it is a little more like `simulateUntil`

Answer (score 2):

The two type signatures are not the same thing at all.  The latter is actually

```
simulateUntil ::
    ...
    -> (a -> (RandomGen g => Rand g Bool))
    -> (Float -> a -> (RandomGen g => Rand g a))
    -> (RandomGen g => Rand g a)
```

I couldn't tell you what aspect of this causes a space leak, but it's a very strange thing to want to do in general, and completely unneccessary here.

Comment: It's worse than that. Your expansion makes it seem as if at least `g` is shared. But it isn't. A synonym declaration like `type SearchEnv a = (RandomGen g) => Rand g a` is the same as saying `type SearchEnv a = forall g. (RandomGen g) => Rand g a`.

Comment: @kosmikus: I see. Can you explain how loss of sharing leads to a space leak there, as I don't understand it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't see it immediately either. Looking at Core, the generated code is subtly different, but nothing immediately screams space leak to me. It's difficult to investigate further because no actual test case is given.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do understand that the type just gets "pasted" into the functions, as you have illustrated here, but I thought it would not matter. I was trying to achieve the effect of having one type which all my methods can work in without the need for later changing all these functions. The problem occurred when I changed from `Rand`in the RandomMonad package to `Rand` in the mwc-random-monad. Few of the other functions needed to be changed, but the simulator code was so old it did not have the type synonym.